# Split large block of text into individual spans with individual ids

Tags: javascript

PLEASE DO NOT MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE! THIS IS THE ONLY PURE JAVASCRIPT APPROACH WITH INDIVIDUAL ID'S

How do I split a large block of text into individual spans with id's that go like this:

```
<span class="word" id="word0">Breaking </span>
<span class="word" id="word1">News. </span>
<span class="word" id="word2">Spring </span>
<span class="word" id="word3">is </span>
<span class="word" id="word4">here </span>
<span class="word" id="word5">to </span>
<span class="word" id="word6">stay. </span>
```

If the input was "Breaking News. Spring is here to stay."

I want to get the input from a specific div and output it into the same div. Please do not use jquery for this.

EDIT: Thanks to Scott Marcus, he gave me this code:

```
/* hw3a.js  */

// your solution here
var button = document.getElementById('divideTranscript');
button.onclick = spanify();
var s = document.getElementById('transcriptText').innerHTML;
function spanify() {
  var arry = s.split(" ");
  var arry = s.split(/\s+/); // This will split on any group of whitespaces

  var output = "";

  var len = arry.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
     output += "<span class='word' id='word" + i + "'>" + arry[i] + "</span>" ;
  }

  s.innerHTML = output;
}
```

But it does not work?

Comment: What code have you written so far to work on this?

Comment: Get the text, split by whitespace, iterate the result, create a span per iteration, give an id based off the iterator, replace the original text.

Comment: Step 1 split the string. Step 2 loop through array of strings. step 3 create dom elements in loop and instert into dom. step 4 test. What part do you not understand about your problem?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Ianardo The down votes are most likely because you didn't show any code that you may have already tried.

Comment: @Ianardo Read my comment below. You are not getting a string initially. You are getting an element.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s = "Breaking News. Spring is here to stay.";
    var arry = s.split(" ");   // This will split on all single whitespaces
    var arry = s.split(/\s+/); // This will split on any group of whitespaces
    
    var output = "";

    var len = arry.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i){
       output += "<span id='word" + i + "'>" + arry[i] + "</span>" ;
    }

    alert(output);

    // Or, to be more core DOM compliant
    var d = document.createElement("div");

    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i){
      var sp = document.createElement("span");
      sp.setAttribute("id", "word" + i);
      sp.textContent = arry[i];
      d.appendChild(sp);
    }

    alert(d.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Why did you use ++i and not i++?

Comment: @Ianardo In many user agents performance tests show that loops that pre increment rather than post increment can run faster. Aslo, notice how the array length is stored prior to the loop, rather than having to fetch it upon each loop iteration?  Faster.

Comment: @Ianardo Your code: `var s = document.getElementById('transcriptText');` returns an **element**. You can't split an element. To get the contents of that element, you'll need: `var s = document.getElementById('transcriptText').textContent;` And, of course, you need to make sure that the `getElementById('transdcriptText')` does, in fact, return an element in the first place.

Comment: It still shows the same error except it says textContent instead of split.

Comment: @Ianardo As I said, you need to make sure that `document.getElementById('transcriptText')` does return an element. The error(s) you are getting indicate the this code is returning nothing and that's why `split()` and `textContent` aren't working.

Comment: How do I do what you just said?

Comment: @Ianardo Add this to your code: `console.log(document.getElementById('transcriptText'))` and look at the results in the console. What does it say?

Comment: This is in my html file:       <div id="transcriptText"></div>
      <br>

Comment: @Ianardo If it says `null`, then the element is not being found and this is the source of your problem. You should post your complete code so we can see what's going on. It may be that you are attempting to find the element before the element has been parsed.

Comment: @Ianardo Unfortunately, that fiddle isn't going to help because we need to see both the HTML and the JavaScript together (as you have it written) in sequence, not split up like fiddle requires. We need to see if you are looking for `transcriptText` before the HTML has been parsed. Post all the code (as it really is) by updating your question.

Comment: @Ianardo What we need is for your post ALL the code in one chunk so that we can see EXACTLY where each piece is in relation to the others. What you've listed is not the entire web page's worth of code and it separates the HTML from the JavaScript.